# Javascript array: Not functioning past 500 elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working in google sheets trying to create an array, however it seems to not work with more than 500 elements.  I've tried initializing the array to the desired length but that didn't work either.

```
var option = [];
...
option = dvSheet.getSheetValues(3,startCol,colLength,1);
```

The code works as intended for all values of colLength <=500.

Please help!

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a limit imposted by Google Sheets? There's nothing about a JavaScript array that's inherently limited to 500 entries (and Google Apps Script is basically an outdated form of JavaScript, so that aspect should be similar).

Comment: If you're using Free license you have limitations on the number of call per minute, day and month, is probably just that.
Free keys have some limitations on calls number.

Comment: What's the exact error you get? Does it match any one of [these](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach I didn't get an error message.

Comment: @T.J Crowder I'm not sure but it's a definite possibility. It doesn't seem like it falls under any of the limitations linked to by Robin.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for me it's not that clear to understand what you really want to do but, the best way for you to get the current sheet data is:

```
function getSheetData(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tab1"),
      // "Data range" gets all rows and columns
      ssData = ss.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Double Array containing all data from "Tab1";
  return ssData;
}
```